# Substitute with contents of register or lines range from elsewhere in file in Vim

Tags: replace, vim, substitution

I'm using Vim, and I want to substitute some placeholder text with a long string, that spans several lines, which is already written somewhere else in the file.

Is it possible to replace a pattern with the contents of a register? Something like

```
:%s/foo/<contents of register A>
```

Otherwise, is it possible to replace with a range of lines? something like

```
:%s/foo/<content of lines from 10 to 15>
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

According to http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace
It appears:

```
:%s/foo/\=@a/g
```

Also, pressing `<c-r>a` while in insert mode will insert the contents of register `a`.

Cool -- I never knew that.  Good question.

Some other things to do with `<c-r>`: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R

Comment: I'm impressed, you answered in less than one minute... Thanks!

Comment: I have always wanted to put things into commands that came from the system clipboard nice work.

Comment: the vimdoc link is broken, use this one: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#CTRL-R

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to work with other replacements like `%s/foo/xxx\=@axxx/g`

Comment: @Wernight ah, yes – I suspect because that parses to "insert from register `axxx`". I don't know off the top of my head how to correctly escape that, but you might be able to get away with typing `%s/foo/xxx` then hitting `<c-r>a`.

Comment: Nice. Note that the same syntax doesn't work for using a register in the search pattern, however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922384

Comment: @Wernight I wanted to do something similar and seeing as how I've kind of learned my way around vim doc now I was able to find what I'm looking for.

`\=` starts a sub-replace-expression. When the substitute string starts with with `\=` it treats the rest of the string as an expression. So instead of doing `%s/foo/xxx\=@xxx/g` you would do the following `%s/foo/\="xxx" . @a . "xxx"\g`.

Comment: @Wernight Could you please post this as an answer so it can be bookmarked?

Answer (score 25):

```
:%s/foo/\=getline(10, 15)/g

:%s/foo/\=join(getline(10, 15))/g
```

Comment: I think that's the opposite of what he's looking for...  I think he wants something like :s/foo/10,15/

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself clearly, but what I wanted to achieve was replacing 'foo' with **the contents** of lines from 10 to 15, and not limit the replacement to lines 10-15. Thanks for answering, anyway :)

Comment: Works perfectly, I'm just sorry I cannot accept more than one answer. Thanks!