# Use a register value as search pattern

Tags: vim

I wish to use the content of a register as search pattern in Vim.

I would like to do this from the command line so I cannot use the `<c-r>` syntax since that assumes an interactive session.

It is possible to use a register as a *replace* pattern, like this

```
:%s/foo/\=@a/g
```

However using this syntax as a *search* pattern does not work

```
:%s/\=@a/foo/g
```

it outputs

```
E64: \= follows nothing
E476: Invalid command
```

Comment: But most people who come here are probably looking for `<C-R>`: [relevant question+answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101258/1143274).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think it's possible directly, but you can use `:exe` to achieve this:

```
:exe '%s/' . @a . '/foo/g'
```

Comment: I prefer this answer since I can pass multiple variables into the script. By way of example, I need determine the search range by two variables I can do it using this: `:exe '/^' . @a . '/,/^' . @b . '/s/' . @c . '/' . @d . '/g'`.

Answer (score 15):

In a pattern (not the replacement part), `\=` stands for “0 or 1 time” (it is a synonym for `\?` put should be preferred over `\?` since the latter means a literal `?` when looking backwards.

See `:help /\=` and `help pattern` for more details.

Why not :

```
let @/=@a
%s//foo/g
```

Comment: I accepted Al's answer since it also works for other commands like ``vimgrep`` (which I was also looking to control).

Comment: No problem. Do not apologize when selecting an answer, we know you can only select one.

Answer (score 11):

## You can do this with the `/` register

This doesn't solve the general problem, but it appears to me that the `/` register is special in this regard: if you leave the search term blank, it will use whatever is in the `/` register; namely, whatever you searched for last.

So if you want to replace `foo` with the contents of `@a`, you could do this:

1. Search for `foo`
2. `%s//\=@a/g` (or highlight some text and start typing `:s` to substitute only in that range)